# When I use JUnit, occur this error. How to solve this error?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

When I use JUnit, I run into this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.mpdidb.mapper.TbUserServiceTest.selectByPrimaryKeyTest(TbUserServiceTest.java:27)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
>     at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)   at
>   com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

And this is my JUnit code:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {RootConfig.class})
public class TbUserServiceTest
{
    @Autowired
    private static TbUserService tbUserService;

    @Test
    public void selectByPrimaryKeyTest()
    {
        String userId = "wusuodai";
        TbUser tbUser = tbUserService.selectByPrimaryKey(userId);
        System.out.println(tbUser.getUserName());
    }
}
```

How to solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Looks like your @Autowired isnt working in this setup and tbUserService is null. Honestly: if you do not know what a NPE is and how to deal with it, than spring and spring-mvc are *not* something you might deal with right now. Rather focus on reading a good book on java **basics**.

Comment: thank you very much. When I run the web application, TbUserService can run normally. But when I junit test will encounter this error, why is this?

Comment: I told you: that field is null; and the logical consequence is that the @Autowired isnt doing its job - most likely because the *framework* that normally "processes" these annotations isnt up. In that sense: do some research how to do unit testing in a spring context. Or do as I said: step back and learn the basics. Learn to crawl before going for **hurdle racing**.

Comment: Hint: you probably want to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21878714/how-to-write-junit-test-with-spring-autowire ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26462926/autowired-with-junit-tests ... as said: you are **not** the first person trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Static fields can not be autowired by field injection. Consider using setter injection.

```
private static TbUserService tbUserService;

@Autowired
public void setTbUserService(TbUserService tbUserService){
  this.tbUserService = tbUserService;
}
```