# How to disable/mock Spring EntityListener in JUnit test

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entitylisteners

In a JUnit test that persists entities, how can I disable or mock a registered  EntityListener?

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(Listener.class)
public class Entity {}

public class Listener {
    @PostPersist
    public void postPersist(Entity entity) {...}
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class Tests {

    //how to disable or mock Listener here?

    @Test
    public void test() {
         ...
         entityRepository.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590917/entitylisteners-injection-junit-testing

Comment: @FrancisRobitaille sure, but I don't want to inject something to my listener. I want to disable the listener while running my Junit tests.

Comment: @cnmuc have you able to handle this to disable/mock the listeners?